# Log-log-scale sns.jointplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to rescale a sns.jointplot to log-log scale. Unfortunately, it does not work with the solutions proposed to two questions already raised in the community.

I tried it with the following code:

```
test_data =pd.concat([ger_empcost['2008'],ger_sales['2008']],axis=1)
test_data.columns = ['X','Y']
test_data[test_data==np.inf] = np.nan
test_data[test_data==-np.inf] = np.nan
test_data = test_data.dropna(how='any')
test_plot = sns.jointplot(test_data['X'],test_data['Y'], kind = 'reg',scatter_kws={'s':10})
test_plot.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
```

and the proposed code in another contribution was:

```
abc = sns.jointplot(x="X",
              y="Y",
              data = test_data,
              kind="reg",
              logx=True,
              )
abc.ax_joint.set_xscale('log')
abc.ax_joint.set_yscale('log')
```

However the results looks as follows:
[image: Results]

Can someone please help me to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Best,
Alex

---

As requested, here are some sample data:
[Test data link](https://unibamberg-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alexander-walter_hempfing_stud_uni-bamberg_de/EZ_n8RBe_9tMsuA1RfTGucEBwR8-NIgI_v2g1nr5aN26WA?e=06Nw98)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], because the second solution works for me

Comment: Thank you for your response @DavidG . I added some test data.

Comment: Hey @DavidG I am wondering if you know by any chance what to do? Do you think it is a Data Problem?

Comment: Probably. Although you have provided a dataset, I don't know how you are reading it in etc. If you make a full [mcve] then it would be easier to try and find the problem